Vscode command to run selection in REPL and maintain focus in editor
It seemed like a simple feature but I am unable figure it out.
What I want:
Work in the editor
Execute a selection of lines in the native REPL
Maintain focus on the editor from which I selected the lines of code
What I have:
python.execSelectionInTerminal: this sends commands to the terminal and it maintains focus on the editor.
python.execInREPL: this sends commands to the REPL but loses focus on the editor
What I tried:
{
        "command": "runCommands",
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
         "args": {
            "commands": [
                "python.execInREPL",
                "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
            ]
        }
    },

but to no avail, my own created command did not set the focus properly. Can someone point me in the right direction? And can someone tell me where I can find documentation on all these workbench.action... and python... commands that I can use? I find it difficult to find that.

note that with https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23843v closed, this should now be the standard behavior for executing to the REPL. So you shouldn't need this workaround

Oh wow.. I just figured it out. I needed to specify which group I want to focus to, because the REPL that starts becomes part of the open editors. So the following command worked for me
{
        "command": "runCommands",
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
         "args": {
            "commands": [
                "python.execInREPL",
                "workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup"
            ]
        }
    },


Hi zwep, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)
